# Rust split Read at offset

Tags: rust

I am trying to split large file into 2 parts without entirely loading them (`Read` or Stream). However after I consume the first reader I do not have access to the original reader again (`use of moved value: file`). Is there some way to duplicate the stream / split it at offset? Or is my approach completely wrong? Thank you.

Code:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("example").unwrap();
    let reader1 = BufReader::new(&mut file.take(1000));
    //Move/Use reader1

    //use of moved value: `file`
    let reader2 = BufReader::new(&mut file.take(1000));
}
```

Comment: "split large file into 2 parts" 2 parts in relation to what? Are you trying to split it into 2 files, or how are you actually using the data (later)?` Regardless, you might be able to utilize [FileExt::read_at()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.FileExt.html)  (Unix) and/or [FileExt::seek_read()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/fs/trait.FileExt.html) (Windows)

Comment: Actually the file is used just as an example - i need to split actual `Read` or `Stream`. The data is consumed by Hyper to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`Read` is implemented for mutable references to `Read`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-14), you can `take` a mutable reference to `file` (this is also what [`Read::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) does, but it shares a name with `Iterator::by_ref` so it's incredibly painful to use):

```rust
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("example").unwrap();

    let mut reader1 = BufReader::new((&mut file).take(1000));

    //Move/Use reader1

    let mut reader2 = BufReader::new((&mut file).take(1000));
}
```

Note that you **must** fully read the 1000 bytes of `reader1`, otherwise `reader2`, which shares the same underlying `Read` instance, will read 1000 bytes starting from what `reader1` didn't read, instead of the next 1000 bytes.

Comment: In my case I get `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

Comment: @MakaloneLOgman You have to make sure `file` lives as long as the two readers do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Read::by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) to apply `take()` to an adapter that refers to the `File` instead of owning it. That way the `BufReader` will not get ownership of the original `File` but of a reference to it, and it will again be accessible once the `BufReader` is dropped:

```
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("example").unwrap();
    let reader1 = BufReader::new(file.by_ref().take(1000));
    // read from `reader1`
    drop(reader1);
    let reader2 = BufReader::new(file.take(1000));
}
```